# ArrayList <Integer> throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have a method that returns an `ArrayList <Integer>`. When i return it and if its null i get a `nullPointerException`. Now i want to have some sort of validation and prevent the null pointer exception hapenning.

These are what i tried, but i still get the `nullpointerexception`

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> personMap = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();

public ArrayList<Integer> method(int departmentID){
  if (personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID)) !=null)
     return personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID));
  else 
     return null;


}
```

I still get the `nullPointerException`.

approach 2.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> method(int departmentID){
  if (personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID)).isEmpty()) return null;
  else return personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID));


}
```

I still get the `nullpointerexception`. Can someone help me solve this ?

From a Testing class i will call the method as follows;

```
Class1 cl = new Class1();

if (c1.method(112121)) // do something
```

Comment: didn't you get compiler error on `Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> personMap = new ArrayList<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();`?

Comment: Can you please upload the stack trace from the NullPointerException?

Comment: are you sure a key for departmentID exists in your map ? maybe you should validate that..

Comment: @Oren the Key departmentID doesn't exist in my Map.. So i will want to capture this and alert the User. How can i do this ?

Comment: i second to Nandkumar Tekale. I am surprised how you are getting nullpointer from a code which is not compilable in first place. And if this is typo .. edit it

Comment: It should be a HashMap @Sikorski

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your `Map` declaration won't compile: -

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> personMap = new ArrayList<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

You should have `new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();` on the RHS.

Secondly, your `if` statement, will again not compile: -

```
if (c1.method(112121))
```

Your `method()` returns an `ArrayList`, whereas in `Java`, you can only have `boolean` value as a condition in `if`.

---

**Modification Needed: -**

You should change your *if* to: -

```
if (c1.method(112121) != null)
```

and use first method.

In fact, you don't need an `if-else` there. You can simply return the value from the map: -

```
public ArrayList<Integer> method(int departmentID){ 
     return personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID));
}
```

Now, this will return `null`, if the key is not in the `HashMap`, else it will return the corresponding `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

If a map doesn't have an entry for a key, `get()` returns `null`.
If you then call `.isEmpty()` on that you get an NPE.

Instead test for `map.get(key) == null` or better, `!map.contains(key)`

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is the same as:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> method(int departmentID){
    return personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID));
}
```

and the second one is clearly able to throw a NPE:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> method(int departmentID){
  if (personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID)).isEmpty()) return null;
  else return personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID));
}
```

If `personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID))` returns null (which it does, when the map has no entry for this key) then calling a method on that throws an NPE:

`if (personMap.get(new Integer(departmentID)).isEmpty())`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would NOT recommend returning null from a method. You should return empty ArrayList.

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> personMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> ();

public ArrayList<Integer> someMethod(int departmentID){

    if (personMap.get(departmentID) !=null)
        return personMap.get(departmentID);
    else
        return new ArrayList<Integer>();

}
```